# .Net DLL object access from javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, dll

I want to call functions from dll from a javascript or jsp. I tried using ActiveXObject, but it is not working. I tried the below one, but I am not able to access the methods.

```
var s = '<OBJECT id="CNS_DLL" classid="CLSID:43F60A01-9AC5-409D-B101-F70C341115AA"></OBJECT>';

var object = document.createElement(s);
object.VFI_getAuthenticate();
```

VFI_getAuthenticate() method is defined in the class specified by the classid.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be be better using a .NET web service which references "your DLL" and makes use of its classes/methods.

Your javascript code will then be able to, indirectly, leverage the code within your class library by calling the web service's methods.

If you want to do the other way around, invoking javascript code from your .NET project, you can use [`SignalR`](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: My project is in java, and i can't create .Net webservice, pls advice me how to access methods of dll from jsp/ javascript. i checked another sample dll, Calculate.dll, which contains method SUM, Mul. ?I am able to access those method correctly, but having issues with this dll. The Calculate.dll is registered using regsvr32.exe command, and the CNS_DLL is registered using RegAsm.exe command. Please suggest what wrong iam doing.

Comment: Please techies, help me on this. I have two dlls. One dll written in VB Com based, and another .NET based. I am able to access the VB Com based dll from my javascript and call methods on it, but not the .Net based.
Please help me techies. I am struck at same issue from few weeks.